# Compatibility Mode for Web Services

Tags: asp.net, visual-c++, compatibility

I have a web service that loads an unmanaged .dll made from VC++ 6.  In Vista and Windows Server 2008, I can get applications using this to work by putting them in Win98 Compatibility mode.  Is there a similar way I can do this with my web service, so it will run?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your unmanaged DLL. I have successfuly deployed unmanaged DLLs that were exposing COM interfaces. After registering those COM components on the target machine (read web server) my managed web application (ASP.NET) were able to call those COM components.

Answer (score 0):

I believe all .dll's prior to VS.NET were "unmanaged".  Do you have access to the source code for this .dll you are referring too?